# Hyperledger Caliper peer nodes performance

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

I run some benchmark tests on my 3node2peer couchdb network with Fabric 1.3

I noticed that in many cases the first peer node (`peer0.org1.example.com` in my case) consumes more RAM and CPU resources.
Is there a reason why this happens?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this difference is significant. But you should inspect the Fabric metrics, and also verify these results with other monitoring tools (like cAdvisor) just to be safe.

Maybe the utilization calculation is wrong in Caliper, it happened before.